# SSMS in SQLCMD mode - Incorrect Syntax

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, ssms, sqlcmd

It is my day for weird errors.

I use a database project and as a part of Post Deployment, we use SQL Scripts to populate data in our tables.

```
alter authorization on database::atlas to sa;
go
ALTER DATABASE ATLAS SET MULTI_USER WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE;
GO

:r C:\Scripts\Script.DisableTriggers.sql
:r C:\Scripts\dbo\Script.dbo.PaymentMethod.sql
:r C:\Scripts\dbo\Script.dbo.TransactionEntryMethod.sql
:r C:\Scripts\dbo\Script.dbo.TransactionTypeGroup.sql
:r C:\Scripts\dbo\Script.dbo.TransactionType.sql
:r C:\Scripts\Script.EnableTriggers.sql
```

each of these scripts is very similar to the one below

```
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[TransactionTypeGroup] ON
INSERT INTO [dbo].[TransactionTypeGroup] (TransactionTypeGroupID,TransactionTypeGroupName) VALUES 
(1,'Inquiry')
, (2,'Points')
, (3,'Board')
, (4,'Guest Meals')
, (5,'Cash Equivalency')
, (6,'Deposits')
, (7,'Void/Void Tender')
, (8,'Refund')
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[TransactionTypeGroup] OFF
GO
```

When I get my output back, I get the following error:

```
(1 row(s) affected)

(1 row(s) affected)

(25 row(s) affected)

(11 row(s) affected)

(2 row(s) affected)

(598 row(s) affected)

(3 row(s) affected)
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 234
Incorrect syntax near 'OFFSET'.
```

I have searched my entire SQL directory, and there is no word called OFFSET in any SQL file or in any command that I am issuing. But yet I get that error..

**Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 234

Incorrect syntax near 'OFFSET'.**

What is going on here?

Comment: just a thought but have you checked the scripts it runs for this?

Comment: @Phil: I checked my entire SQL directory for the word OFFSET and did not find it anywhere.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is baadddddddd

It will concatenate commands together from file to file

One file ended this way

```
SET IDENTITY_INSERT TABLEONE OFF
```

Next file started this way

```
SET IDENTITY_INSERT TABLETWO ON
```

But the first file did not have a blank line after the SET IDENTITYINSERT OFF.

SSMS was putting the two files together and executing them, so the output became

```
SET IDENTITY_INSERT TABLEONE OFFSET IDENTITY_INSERT TABLETWO ON
```

and that's how this error came up

```
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 234
Incorrect syntax near 'OFFSET'.
```

Horrendous.

[I just submitted a bug into Microsoft Connect.](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/ViewFeedback.aspx?FeedbackID=485312)

Comment: Did each file not end with a "GO" line (with CR/LF after the GO)?

Comment: LOL. It was the missing/needed/required/mandatory CR/LF that was causing the issue. Would GO have made a difference? I think it would have errored out on GOSET instead of OFFSET.

Answer (score 1):

Did you check if a trigger is firing in Script.EnableTriggers.sql?  If you don't know your trigger code, try this:

```
select * from sys.sql_modules where definition like '%OFFSET%'
```

Let me know if you find anything.

Thanks,
Eric

Comment: It is SQL 2008. I ran - select * from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.ROUTINES 
where ROUTINES.ROUTINE_BODY like '%OFFSET%' ... but zero rows returned

Comment: Sorry, I meant to say sys.sql_module.  This is corrected.  If you use routines, you don't get trigger definitions, which is what we're interested in.  Can you try the query above?

Comment: @Strommy: it wasnt a module of code, but bad behavior from SSMS itself. Check out my answer.